# How to color table entries based on value

Tags: html, css, colors, html-table

What I want to do is make all the `<td>`-entries with the content "x" red.

So in:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Mini Contests</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the last 4 entries should be red.

Comment: you cannot do this with html and css only

Comment: use inline css for td

Comment: use `tr td:child(3){color:red}` in css

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use nth-last-child for styling the TDs.
This code will effect the last 4 items (changes color to red):

```
td:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
    color: red;
}
```

And this one makes their backgrounds red:

```
td:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
        background: red;
    }
```

Comment: You missed the part where it says "based on value".

Answer (score 0):

You can't without adding an element with a class surrounding the X.

```
<td><span class="redbg">x</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it you can do as follow:

1st: In the begin of page set class

```
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

2nd: then put you table and other html code

3rd: In the end of page use javascript that apply class `red` to all cells containing "x":

```
<script>
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
      if(cells[i].innerHTML == "x") cells[i].className = "red";
  }
</script>
```

Below is a working example:

```js
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
      if(cells[i].innerHTML == "x") cells[i].className = "red";
  }
```

```css
.red {
    background: red;
}

td{
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Mini Contests</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5.0</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```